# how to check via ExcelVBA if given file in directory has a change in the current month

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to aggregate some values using from 2 to 3 different excel files via VBA. This works fine, but I want to implement a check if the available files in the directory are current (i.e. from the current month).
Can i somehow check if the "change date" property of an xlsx is from the current month?
Tbf, i wouldnt even know where to begin. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656023/vba-how-to-get-the-last-modified-file-or-folder-in-a-directory-in-excel-2010